# error: request for member ‘table’ in something not a structure or union C

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

So I'm getting this error. I understand that the error is telling me that I'm not actually pointing to a struct, but I cant seem to figure out why. Here's my code.

```
 typedef struct {
   char * word;
   char * defn;
 } entry;


 typedef struct {
   int size;
   struct entry **table;
 } hashTable;

 typedef hashTable * Dictionary;

 Dictionary create(int initial_capacity, int delta_capacity){
     Dictionary *new_table;
     int i;

     if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(Dictionary))) == NULL){
         return NULL;
     }

     if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(entry *) * initial_capacity)) == NULL){
         return NULL;
     }

     for(i=0; i < initial_capacity; i++){
         new_table->table[i] = NULL;
     }
     return new_table;
 }
```

These are the two compiler errors I get.

```
 hashP.c: In function ‘create’:
 hashP.c:15:16: error: request for member ‘table’ in something not a structure or union
   if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(entry *) * initial_capacity)) == NULL){

 hashP.c:20:12: error: request for member ‘table’ in something not a structure or union
    new_table->table[i] = NULL;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef hashTable * Dictionary;
```

By hiding a pointer behind a typedef, you managed to trick yourself into not understanding your own code. Because `Dictionary *new_table` is actually a `struct hashTable**` which is not what you want.

Simply never hide pointers behind typedefs and all problems will go away.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got rid of that pointer and I'm not getting those errors anymore. My only issue now is that I'm not sure if I'm allowed to alter that typedef, because that's part of the header file provided by my prof.

Comment: So I was able to get it to work without modifying my profs header file as well by changing `Dictionary *new_table` to `Dictionary new_table`.

Comment: @jay Yes that will work, but just keep in mind that it is bad practice to hide pointers like that, no matter what your professor says.

Comment: Ok I'll remember that.  Thanks for all the help.